# How to fix UKUI panel in Ubuntu Kylin 17.04

Tags: desktop-environments

I do not see the panel where I run the programs.
The terminal works properly.

Comment: Do you see anything graphical load? Any errors?

Comment: Some x panel not  show in UKUI deskop,all grapich interface show.How to restart  x panel .

Comment: **LQ Reviewers:** Someone understood exactly what this was about and answered...

Answer (score 1):

The following command will launch the panel:

```
mate-panel &
```

but it should auto start, do you have a mate-panel.desktop in `/usr/share/ukui/applications` ? if not, you should:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/mate-panel.desktop /usr/share/ukui/applications/
sudo vim /usr/share/ukui/applications/mate-panel.desktop
```

and change the `OnlyShowIn=MATE;` to `OnlyShowIn=MATE;UKUI;`, and then reboot.